# Batch file print files with specific extensions

Tags: batch-file

I am completely new to batch file programming, so i am a bit lost here, anyway is it posible to do this ?

i have in `c:\myfolder`
txt files, pdf, xls, bat, and other. I would like to have a loop to identify  all the files that are not pdf, or tif, or bat, and in that case I would run a command to convert that file to pdf, with this command :

```
C:\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe /PrintFile="C:\myFolder\theFileNameToConvert"
```

the conversion might take about 10 second up to 20 in case of bigger files

thanks
Carlos

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *') do if /i "%%~xa" neq ".pdf" if /i "%%~xa" neq ".tif" if /i "%%~xa" neq ".bat" C:\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe /PrintFile="C:\myFolder\%%~na"
```

should do what you want - provided your `C:\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe` command is correct - it appears to specify the printfile but not the source file.

The `for /f` reads each line of `dir /b /a-d` (directory list, basic [filenames only] without directory names) and assigns each in turn to the meatvariable `%%a`. `%%~xa` means the extension, so the three cascaded `if`s mean if (/i = case-insensitive) the extension for the file "%%a" is NotEQual to potatoes then do the next test. Gets through all of the NotEQual testss, then execute the `PDFCreator` command, using `%%~na` - the name-part only of the file `%%a`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `PDFCreator` needs `%%a`(name and extension), not `%%~na` (name only). Otherwise, how can it possibly find the file?

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, assuming current directory is `"c:\myFolder":

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr /live ".pdf .tif .bat"') do C:\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe /PrintFile="%F"
```

Double the percents if in a batch file: (I've also formatted the code across multiple lines for easier viewing)

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\myFolder"
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d^|findstr /live ".pdf .tif .bat"'
) do C:\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe /PrintFile="%%F"
popd
```

Comment: `findstr /live` is nice. I like it.

Comment: @Endoro - There is also `/vile` and `/evil`